# Data in rows changing on scrolling the DataGrid (Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

I have added different rows in a dataGrid e.g. 30 row.  When scroll appears on silverlight grid. The data in the different rows changes.

I have changed the the event. No event is changing the data in the row. But on the display the data is changed.

Why this is happening with this dataGrid??
Is there any specific event with is doing this???

Comment: Hint: The Virtualizating. The Virtualizating Attached Property is on by default.

Comment: I have fixed it by removing the height from the datagrid and removing the scroll bars and putting the datagrid into a scrollviewer. BUT I would still really like to know what is wrong with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have fixed it by giving the auto height to DataGrid and removing the scroll bars and putting the `DataGrid` into a `ScrollViewer`.

**BUT**

I would still really like to know what is wrong with this.

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU after hours of battling with an infragistics xamgrid (silimar to silverlight datagrid) that was seemingly randomly copying values into different rows while scrolling i finally luckily found your solution THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently having a similar issue with ComboBoxes inside my DataGrid.  After some research I think I found out why.  When a row becomes visible (i.e., you scroll down and a previously hidden row is now in view) the Row_Loading event fires and re-initializes the ComboBoxes inside that row (apparently due to Row Virtualization as Dipak mentioned above).

This link for Silverlight 3, but I am having the same issues using Silverlight 4, so I am assuming SL4 has the same issue:

http://forums.silverlight.net/t/125209.aspx/1

Another link with a similar solution to what you did, basically turning off Row Virtualization manually and by turning off vertical scrolling and placing the RowPresenter inside a ScrollViewer.

http://forums.silverlight.net/p/101075/230671.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Actucally when u load a grid not all the rows are created first time as soon as you scroll the rows gets created and deleted so when u mark sonething suppose a checkbox in the first row and scroll to the bottom row then when u scroll back again u see a recreated row without checkbox selection.
Hopes that explains...

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago, but had the same issue with Infragistiscs XamDataGrid.

Binding the same Property to two fields causing this error.

```
                        <ig:Field Column="1" Name="ArtNrID" Label="{l:Translate PriceList_ArtNr}" Width="80">
                            <ig:Field.Settings>
                                <ig:FieldSettings AllowEdit="True" LabelHeight="23"/>
                            </ig:Field.Settings>
                        </ig:Field>
                <ig:Field Column="2" Name="ArtBez" Label="{l:Translate PriceList_ArtBez}" Width="80">
                    <ig:Field.Settings>
                        <ig:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" LabelHeight="23"/>
                    </ig:Field.Settings>
                </ig:Field> 
                <!--<ig:UnboundField Column="2" Name="ArtNrBez" Label="{l:Translate PriceList_ArtBez}" Width="Auto">
                            <ig:Field.Settings>
                                <ig:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" LabelHeight="23">
                                    <ig:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}" >
                                            <Style.Setters>
                                                <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="ArtBez"/>
                                                <Setter Property="ValuePath" Value="ArtNrID"/>
                                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Value.ArticleList, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"/>
                                                <Setter Property="DropDownButtonDisplayMode" Value="OnlyInEditMode"/>
                                                <Setter Property="IsInEditMode" Value="False"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Value" Value="{Binding DataItem.ArtNrID}"/>
                                            </Style.Setters>
                                        </Style>

                                    </ig:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                </ig:FieldSettings>
                            </ig:Field.Settings>
                        </ig:UnboundField>-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and was able to correct it by setting virtualization to false in my datagrid xaml.

```
VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
```